# Dependency injection in Azure web jobs - scoped dependencies are reused in subsequent calls

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-webjobs

We are in the process of migrating a .net framework web jobs implementation to dotnet core. I'm using the documented extension method (IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices) on IHostBuilder to register dependencies with the scopes that seem fit, i.e., scoped, because most of the time I want an instance per web job invocation.

In the unit of work implementation that we use, the Entity Framework DbContext is disposed when the unit of work completes. In local development, and this is the issue that leads to this question, I bump into the issue that a second trigger (the web job is triggered via a ServiceBusTrigger) reuses the same instances of my dependencies, while they are properly registered on the IServiceCollection via the regular AddScoped<,> API. In my scenario, this manifests itself a DisposedObjectException on the DbContext.

While investigating this, I found that all scoped services are reused over invocations, which leads to the question whether you have to do the scoping differently in Azure Webjobs? Is this a local development thing only?

So, in pseudo code, this is how stuff is implemented:

```
// Program.cs
public static async Task Main()
{
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureLogging((ctx, loggingBuilder) => { /* ... */});
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(webJobsBuilder => {
   // DO STUFF
   webJobsBuilder.AddServiceBus(options => { /* ... */ });
});
builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
   services.AddScoped<IService, ServiceImplementation>();
   // ...
   services.AddScoped<IContextFactory, ContextFactoryImplementation>();
   // ...
});
var host = builder.Build();
using(host)
{
   await host.RunAsync();
}
}
```

And the unit of work is basically:

```
public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
   public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
   {
      // ...
   }

   public void Commit()
   {
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      ...
   }

   public void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      ...
      dbContext?.Dispose();
      dbContext = null;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a local development issue - I deployed to Azure and tested.

Comment: How do you instanciate your ```IUnitOfWork```? Is it done via a ```IHostedService```?

Comment: What is your version of [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/)? Also check https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2173#issuecomment-512960008

Comment: The unit of work is instantiated via a factory, which itself is registered scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, sorry to waste your time, it turns out that a particular service was incorrectly registered as a singleton. I have to admit I might have jumped to conclusions, given that recently we bumped into the issues op scoped services in combination with usage of HttpClient(Factory) in Azure Functions (which is a real problem).